# Is it possible to have MySQL/MariaDB bidirectional replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, mysql-replication, database-replication

I am trying to install replication on several MariaDB servers.
With no experience at all on this.

I am wondering something.

Would it be possible to have both servers acting simultaneously as master and as slave for each others, **for different databases**?

The idea would be replicating some databases from one main server to a slave server, then running some periodical heavy loading post-processing on these databases replications on the slave, writing results to other database(s), then replicating back these resulting databases from the slave server to the master server, meaning that **for these resulting databases**, the slave would become master and the master would become slave.

(unless it would be possible to filter replication on tables rather than on databases?)

Comment: What version?..

Comment: This was a quite generic question, but on the multiple servers I have, MariaDB versions can be 10.3.38 or 10.5.19 or 10.6.12.
Servers are Linux Debian 10, Linux Debian 11 or Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, each server can act as both Primary and Replica.
- Replicating from a higher version to a lower version *may not* work.  See [https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-overview/#:~:text=The%20main%20mechanism%20used%20in,access%20the%20data%20to%20replicate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-overview/#:%7E:text=The%20main%20mechanism%20used%20in,access%20the%20data%20to%20replicate).  (The table there may be pessimistic and cautious.)
- Replicating a subset of the data...  Configure with `binlog-do-...` on each server.  `replicate-...` is probably unnecessary.
- Use `binlog-format=ROW`

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I will consider that.
But why should I use binlog-format=ROW ?<br/>
And by the way, I just asked [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1140897/using-mysql-mariadb-replication-how-to-know-when-the-replica-is-in-a-consistent) related to the same idea.