# Using MySQL/MariaDB replication, how to know when the Replica is in a consistent state?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, mysql-replication, database-replication

This is a question about MariaDB (mostly) and a replication that I am considering.

For this replication, the Primary database is updated every minute by a process which can take about 15 seconds to complete, each time.
During these 15 seconds, the Primary database may not be completely consistent on each tables.

I want to set a Replica for this database on another server.
On the Replica server, I expect to do some periodic post-processing on this database, which needs (preferably) the database to be in a consistent state (and maybe writing the results back to the Primary server, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1140803/is-it-possible-to-have-mysql-mariadb-bidirectional-replication/1140837)).

Is there a way to know when the Replica has fully replicated this consistent state, or to force it to stay in this state, in order I can do the post-processing without errors?

(On the multiple servers I have, MariaDB versions can be 10.3.38 or 10.5.19 or 10.6.12. Servers are Linux Debian 10, Linux Debian 11 or Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS).

Comment: `Seconds_behind_master` is not definitive, but it is probably the best available.  What the heck takes 15 minutes?  Can that be sped up?

Comment: I said 15 seconds, not 15 minutes.

Comment: Inject (into an extra table) some indication that the periodic update is finished.

Comment: SQL Transactions are there to keep the database consistent whenever you need to do complex data modifications.

Comment: This extra table would also need to be part of the replication.
Can I be sure it will be replicated in strict order?

And about SQL Transactions … replicating them will certainly, nevertheless, need some time. Can I be sure that they will be atomic in the Replica?

Comment: @GingkoFr - The general answer to those questions is " all will work correctly".  However, since there are ways to bypass things, we would need to seep specifics to confirm it.